# Microsoft Bot Framework - Directline Task Cancelled

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

We have been using the Microsoft bot framework + directline for more than a year now. Since a few weeks, we are seeing this error :

"System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException","Message":"A task was canceled"

This seems to happen when the Bot server (azure web app) is trying to post something back to the user. We are using DirectLine + websockets, bot v3 sdk.

From other posts, it seems that this error is happening when the bot is not responding but we dont know how to debug this one... The bot server has never been down / no increase in the response time...

Any reason why this error is suddenly happening ? Any issue on the Azure infrastructure / directline services in the last few weeks ?

Comment: Since you're saying that everything was fine for more than a year now, and you didn't change anything, then what about the users? Did they increase? If yes, then did you scale up? Because maybe you need to upgrade your service plan to handle more users!

Comment: @Ali my bot channel registration plan is already a S1, I cannot get higher right? And my bot web site is a Premium Large!

Comment: Just saw this : https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4738 which may explain this behavior...

Comment: [Azure status history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ4Qk.png) indicates the issue seems to be mitigated, if you are still running into this issue, you can try to open a [new github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues) to report it.

Comment: We got this error again this morning. Just raised an issue here : https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4754

Comment: I've responded to the GitHub issue.